# How to Create Ubuntu Desktop html5 Web Apps

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

How to Create Ubuntu Desktop html5 Web Apps

please help me!!!!

Comment: this question better suites on ***SO***.

Comment: @adityapatil - and would probably be ignored as the OP has not shown their current efforts...

Comment: @Wilf This question shows no research effort, it is clear but not much useful.Has the mixed properties of an good and bad question.

Comment: @adityapatil - Not every question can be a good question - though it would be interesting to find an answer.

Comment: @Wilf Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/423620/184942) answer interesting?

Answer (score 1):

Use **Ubuntu SDK**

You can install it by typing in the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

alternately, open USC and search for Ubuntu sdk and click install.

In SDK, you can select *file*->*new*-> *HTML5 Touch UI*
[image]

[**Reference**](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/html-5/get-started/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use any HTML5 framework to do that.

For instance I like [Kendoui](http://kendoui.com)

Comment: Server not found for the link...

Comment: Do you mean [`http://labs.kendoui.com/`](http://labs.kendoui.com/), [`http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui`](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui), or something?